# DAX formula to count group by with filter

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table like below in power BI with two columns Category and subcategory. I m trying to get the count of subcategory="S2" for each category into a calculated column (like in S2_count).

```
Category    Subcategory S2_count
  A           S1        1
  A           S2        1
  A           S1        1
  B           S1        2
  B           S3        2
  B           S2        2
  B           S2        2
  C           S2        2
  C           S3        2
  C           S2        2
```

Is there a way using the DAX to get this ? I tried the below formula but no clue how to apply both filter and group by

```
s2_count = 
            CALCULATE(
              COUNT(Test01[subcategory]),
                   GROUPBY(Test01,Test01[subcategory]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thy this:

```
s2_count =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        'Test01',
        'Test01'[Category] = EARLIER ( 'Test01'[Category] )
            && 'Test01'[Subcategory] = "S2"
    )
)
```

The EARLIER Function will return 'Test01'[Category] in its previous filtercontext, which is the rowcontext.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using `CALCULATE`.

```
s2_count =
CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( Test01 ),
    Test01[Subcategory] = "S2",
    ALLEXCEPT( Test01, Test01[Category] )
)
```

The `ALLEXCEPT` function removes any of the row context except for the `Category`.

---

Note: If there are no other columns in your table, you don't need the `ALLEXCEPT` argument and you can just use this instead:

```
s2_count = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( Test01 ), Test01[Subcategory] = "S2" )
```

If you do have other columns though, they are passed from row context to filter context along with the `Category` and you won't get the right result.