# Power BI - countif / averageif with dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

New to DAX. I need a bit of help when moving excel formulas to DAX. I have this table and call it table1:

```
Date        ID  Time
10/06/2020  1   1
10/06/2020  1   2
11/06/2020  1   3
12/06/2020  2   5
13/06/2020  1   6
```

And I need to calculate count and average per day per ID. The results with two simple formulas `(=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,A2))` and `(=AVERAGEIFS(C:C,B:B,B2,A:A,A2))` in excel is:

```
Date        ID  Time    Count ifs   Avergae ifs
10/06/2020  1   1       2           1.5
10/06/2020  1   2       2           1.5
11/06/2020  1   3       1           3
12/06/2020  2   5       1           5
13/06/2020  1   6       1           6
```

How can I replicate in DAX?

**Update**

Count in DAX

```
DAX Count = 
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        'Table1',
        'Table1'[ID] = EARLIER ( 'Table1'[ID] )
            &&  'Table1'[Date] = EARLIER ( 'Table1'[Date] )
    )
)
```

**Sum per day per ID**

```
Sum = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Table1[Time]),
    FILTER(
        All(Table1),
        Table1[ID] = EARLIER(Table1[ID]) &&
        Table1[Date] = EARLIER(Table1[Date])
    )
)
```

Item closed :)

Comment: Are you trying to write a measure or a calculated column?

Comment: Actually, both and I would need the dynamic changes when displaying the results.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442875 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645281

Comment: I have count done. `DAX Count = 
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        'Table1',
        'Table1'[ID] = EARLIER ( 'Table1'[ID] )
            &&  'Table1'[Date] = EARLIER ( 'Table1'[Date] )
    )
)` but need a bit more help with the average.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered the question. @Alexis Olson thank you for the inspiration.

Count in DAX

```
DAX Count = 
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        'Table1',
        'Table1'[ID] = EARLIER ( 'Table1'[ID] )
            &&  'Table1'[Date] = EARLIER ( 'Table1'[Date] )
    )
)

Sum per day per ID

Sum = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Table1[Time]),
    FILTER(
        All(Table1),
        Table1[ID] = EARLIER(Table1[ID]) &&
        Table1[Date] = EARLIER(Table1[Date])
    )
)
```

Comment: Please put your solution in this answer rather than in the comments.