# DAX: Filter, group by and count distinct values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I filter the table by `Category = Animal`, then group by Class, and count the distinct id for each group?

So far I can only group by and count distinct values:

```
output = SUMMARIZE(my_table, my_table[Class], "Distinct Count", DISTINCTCOUNT(my_table[Id]))
```

I tried:

```
output = CALCULATETABLE(SUMMARIZE(my_table, my_table[Class]), DISTINCTCOUNT(my_table[Id]), FILTER(my_table, my_table[Category ] = "Animal"))
```

which caught error:

```
The True/False expression does not specify a column. Each True/False expressions used as a table filter expression must refer to exactly one column.
```

I also tried the way suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52645281/11901732) but it only counts the number of rows in the table rather than the distinct number of `Id`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
output =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    my_table[Class],
    TREATAS ( { "Animal" }, my_table[Category] ),
    "Distinct Count", DISTINCTCOUNT ( my_table[Id] )
)
```

Another option:

```
output =
CALCULATETABLE (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( my_table[Class] ),
        "Distinct ID", CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( my_table[Id] ) )
    ),
    my_table[Category ] = "Animal"
)
```

SUMMARIZECOLUMNS version is generally an optimized way of writing the code so you should prefer that one. I have included ADDCOLUMNS/CALCULATETABLE construct only for the learning purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [Filter SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59931193/1903793)

You filter in this way:

```
VAR  __MyFilterTable = FILTER( ALL(T[category]), T[category] = "animal" ) 

RETURN
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    T[category],
    __MyFilterTable
)
```

Or even shorter:

```
VAR  __MyFilterTable = TREATAS ({"animal"}, T[category] )

RETURN
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    T[category],
    __MyFilterTable
)
```